# Accessing Environment Variables from Jenkins using Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, jenkins

I'm trying to execute the following Powershell script during the Jenkins build process:

```
Write-Host ==================================================
Write-Host Setting Version to $env:Version BEGIN
(Get-Content .\MyFile.js) -replace '"Version"\s*:\s*".*"', '"Version" : "$env:Version"' | Out-File .\MyFile.js
Write-Host Setting Version to $env:Version COMPLETE
Write-Host ==================================================
```

The first and last instances of $env:Version get substituted correctly.  I see the output

```
==================================================
Setting Version to 1.2.3.4 BEGIN
Setting Version to 1.2.3.4 COMPLETE
==================================================
```

But the second instance of $env:Version does not get replaced in MyFile.js.  When I open up MyFile.js, I see the following:

```
"Version" : "$env:Version",
```

How can I pass this environment variable to the Get-Content command?  Is it something about regular expressions (triggered by -replace) that is preventing the substitution from happening?

Answer (score 3):

You have that string in single quotes which wont allow the variable to expand.

```
'"Version" : "$env:Version"'
```

Could be this instead. We use backticks to escape the quotes so the interpreter does not eat them up. Might need a subexpression as well.

```
"`"Version`" : `"$($env:Version)`""
```

or as per Etan Reisner's solution

```
('"Version" : "{0}"' -f $env:version)
```

Could even improve on that `-replace` as well I think and make it cleaner. Use a capture group to hold the first part of the string, as `$1`, since it will remain the same. The use the format operator to add in the `$env:version` so we don't need a subexpression.

```
-replace '("Version"\s*:\s*)".*"',('$1"{0}"' -f $env:version)
```

Comment: Use of `('"Version" : "{0}"' -f $env:version)` might be better here (to avoid needing the backticks, etc.).

Comment: Backticks don't seem to be helping.  I'll try to implement Etan's suggestion, though.

Comment: Hmm thats odd. I just tried it again and it was working. Have a look at my second solution as well.

Comment: So @EtanReisner 's suggestion worked - Thanks!  The final command that I used was:

`(Get-Content .\MyFile.js) -replace '"Version"\s*:\s*".*"', ('"Version" : "{0}"' -f $env:Version) | Out-File .\MyFile.js`